# Link variable to data set in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm using JMeter 3.2 to create some performance tests.

I have a set up where a thread group has multiple threads (users) which perform multiple loops requesting a resource, form a server, every time.

Each of the threads go through an once only controller which retrieves a token from a server, which identifies the user, and is required on all subsequent requests. The token is different every time it is generated, I cannot store it in a data set (csv) as it would later be invalid.

I have a data set (.csv file) containing username and password of my test users.

So far so good.. Now the threads need to request a resource on the server requiring the token to be sent. It goes well the first time, but the second time it starts messing up. It seems like each iteration uses data from the next row in the dataset, but the token retrieved (from the once only controller) is not linked to row of data (username and password) used, so something like this happens:

> thread1: data1/token1 - good
>
> thread2: data2/token2 - good
>
> Perhaps thread2 finishes first and starts the new iteration:
>
> thread2: data1/token2 - error
>
> thread1: data2/token1 - error

So my question is: how can I link the token retrieved to a row in data set (as a variable), so that the correct token will be sent every time that piece of data is used for a request?

**Edit**
I have an idea. Creating a Hashtable with some data, from the data set, as key and the token as value, but I have some issue. I've created the following code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
map = new Hashtable();
vars.putObject("map", map);
```

but it cast the following error:

```
java.util.Hashtable cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, though it might not be the most optimal solution. What I did is to create a property (variables won't work), which is a JSONObject. In this I can store an id (for my data) and the token linked to it. I transform it to a string and store it in the property.

In a preprocessor to the http request requiring the token I retrieve the property and parses it back to a JSONObject and can look up the token using the id.